# Erlang ssl: password option for private key

Tags: ssl, erlang, elixir

#### Context

Using Elixir and [Brod](https://github.com/klarna/brod) (which relies on Erlang's `ssl` module), I'm trying to connect to a SSL-enabled Kafka broker. This works if, and only if, the private key of the client certificate is *not* password-protected.

The certificate is created using `openssl`:

```
$ openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -passout pass:test1234 -keyout client.key -out client.csr -days $DAYS -subj "$SUBJ"
$ openssl x509 -req -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -in client.csr -out client.crt -days $DAYS -CAserial ca.sr
```

I verify that the password is set using `openssl rsa -noout -text -in certs/client.key`.

After that, `client.key` looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIFHzBJBgkqhkiG9w0BBQ0wPDAbBgkqhkiG9w0BBQwwDgQIttCU1ZmyY2ACAggA
...
6C/BxoJnc6SQODqj+eiZHsCTKQ==
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

..which I suppose is in PEM format, suitable for Erlang's `ssl` module.

#### Configuration

Brod passes the SSL options down to Erlang's `ssl:connect`. I'm passing these options (Elixir syntax):

```
[
  certfile: "client.crt",
  keyfile: "client.key",
  password: String.to_charlist("test1234"),
  cacertfile: "ca.crt"
]
```

#### The Error Message

```
** (stop) {{{:failed_to_upgrade_to_ssl, {:keyfile, :function_clause}}, [{:brod_sock, :maybe_upgrade_to_ssl, 4, [file: 'src/brod_sock.erl', line: 278]}, {:brod_sock, :do_init, 4, [file: 'src/brod_sock.erl', line: 204]}, {:brod_sock, :init, 5, [file: 'src/brod_sock.erl', line: 176]}, {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 247]}]}, [localhost: 9193]}
    (brod) src/brod_client.erl:708: :brod_client.start_metadata_socket/5
    (brod) src/brod_client.erl:301: :brod_client.handle_info/2
    (stdlib) gen_server.erl:616: :gen_server.try_dispatch/4
    (stdlib) gen_server.erl:686: :gen_server.handle_msg/6
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

According to *The Internet* this error means that the private key file could not be parsed/loaded/used. I've tried using a wrong password and it's the exact same message. As noted above, when using a secret key that's not password protected, it works fine.

#### Ideas

- Is something wrong with `client.key`'s formatting?
- Do I have to specify the password in another way?

Currently studying the OTP sources, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar problem. It turned out that the private key was encoded using `AES-256-CBC`, but the `public_key` library in Erlang/OTP doesn't support it. This is the function call that fails:

```
** exception error: no function clause matching pubkey_pbe:decode(...,
             "password","AES-256-CBC", ...) (pubkey_pbe.erl, line 59)
 in function  public_key:do_pem_entry_decode/2 (public_key.erl, line 976)
```

The actual code in Erlang/OTP is at [github](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/d9d694ca3ea8a168c51145fc485a3bcbc18f6188/lib/public_key/src/pubkey_pbe.erl#L55) and we can see that "AES-256-CBC" is not handled.

Comment: Thanks for also adding the source link!

Answer (score 1):

After investigating some more I found out that the Erlang ssl implementation doesn't play well with the private key created by openssl req -newkey. In the openssl documentation I couldn't find the exact algorithm used by -newkey, but creating the private key beforehand using openssl genrsa -des3 did the trick, so I think the default algorithm is something not supported by Erlang's ssl.

I'm posting this as an answer as it solves my problem, but I'd very much appreciate any additional insights.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a suggestion. I do not have enough reps to provide this in comments.
Try giving the password as binary string.